# Parse error in events.js in hybrid angular app

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working over creating a hybrid angular app using angular js and angular5. I have installed angular5 project with in the angular js project using angular-cli
I have written the code for bootstrapping also. But facing the below error during gulp serve

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Parse Error: <textarea id="base64" cols=32" rows="4" onkeyup="
    $('srctxt').value = Base64.decode(this.value);
    doit();
    if (1 /*@cc_on -1 @*/) $('data').src = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + this.valu
e;
```

Not sure y?
Please guide.

Comment: First there is a little error here `cols=32"` (missing `"`) but i doubt it's the problem. Your selectors seem to be missing a `.` (class) or `#` (id) at the start. `$('srctxt')` actually tries to select a `<srctxt>` html tag, which i bet is not found. By the way, interacting with the DOM with jQuery (assuming it is jQuery) in Angular is not really the cleanest way.

Comment: I am unable to see the index.html file under my dist folder.Can this be the reason for this error and do u have any idea how does index.html comes under dist folder. I am using a hybrid app..and trying to run index.html from js framework.